# MediaElement won't play files that are outside the project's directory

Tags: c#

This app needs to play audio/video/ssml(xml) files using `dispatcherTimer` and `TimePicker` to choose when the file is played using the MediaElement Control.

Using `FilePicker`, the `MediaElement` plays files fine that are located Inside the project's Assets directory. But when I pick a file outside the project's directory,
like "C:\Users\Flazz\Music\AV\PlayLibray\Audio\Filename1.mp3" it does not do anything.

I tried the Add linked file, but option does no exist in VS 2017. Supposedly the VisualStudios team is aware they need to look into this oversight. Still, there has to be a simple solution.

Maybe my path is wrong so here is the code:

```
  public UC_Mood()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        PickAFileButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(PickAFileButton_Click);
        PickAFileButton2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(PickAFileButton2_Click);
        PickAFileButton3.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(PickAFileButton3_Click);
        PickAFileButton4.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(PickAFileButton4_Click);
    }
    const string ENV_PROJ_PATH = "ms-appx:///Assets/AV/PlayLibray/Audio/";
    const string ENV_CENTRAL_PATH = @"C:\Users\Flazz\Music\AV\PlayLibray\Audio\";
```

Click event handler with `FileOpenPicker` code:

```
private async void PickAFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear previous returned file name, if it exists, between iterations of this scenario
        tbFilePicked.Text = "";

        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".m4a");     
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".m4v");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".avi");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xml");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
            tbFilePicked.Text = file.Name;
            Debug.WriteLine(ENV_CENTRAL_PATH + tbFilePicked.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            tbFilePicked.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
        }
    }
```

`Timer_Tick` with `MediaElement` where any file path that is outside the Projects path does not play:

*note - Path that is declared above  `const string ENV_CENTRAL_PATH = @"C:\Users\Flazz\Music\AV\PlayLibray\Audio\";`

```
 private void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        CountDown--;
        txtCountDown.Text = CountDown.ToString();
        if ((CountDown <= 0))
        {
            CountDown = 0;
            try
            {
                 MediaTool.Source = new Uri(ENV_CENTRAL_PATH + tbFilePicked.Text);
               // MediaTool.Source = new Uri(ENV_PROJ_PATH + tbFilePicked.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            MediaTool.Volume = 100;
            MediaTool.Play();
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you do not have a exception or even place of error to go by, there is pretty little we can help you with. 
Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine, and unfortunately you commit the (very common) beginner mistakes. If you do not have a exception message, that means you have no information to debug. Here are two articles on the amter that I do link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: It does not throw an exception. I Read your link and it occurred to me, duhh, I can create my own. So I will. So I'd guess my path does look correct or you would have also pointed that out. Thanks Adam

Comment: @user6173057: It is really odd that it simply "does nothing". If anything build in classes are know to throw exceptions too agressively. So that makes it very likely that there is a exception that you just swallow.